# Replace all div tags of each row of a table

Tags: javascript, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to replace a div tag that is the same on each row of a dynamically created table. I'm not sure how to go about it. Right now I can get the function to work but it only replaces the first row of div tags. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Calc() {
    var qty = 0;
     qty=parseInt(document.getElementById('qtyEntry').value);
    var weight = parseInt(document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML);
    var cube = parseInt(document.getElementById('cube').innerHTML);
    var carton = parseInt(document.getElementById('carton').innerHTML);

     var newWeight = 0;
     var newCube = 0;
     var newCarton = 0;

    newWeight = qty *weight ;
    newCube = qty * cube;
    newCarton = qty * carton;

     document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML = newWeight;
     document.getElementById('cube').innerHTML = newCube;
     document.getElementById('carton').innerHTML = newCarton;
}
```

```
  @{int seq=0;
               foreach (var item in Model)
               {
                   seq++;
                <tr>
                  <td>@seq</td>
                    <td>@item.sku</td>
                    <td>@item.description</td>
                    <td><input type=text id="qtyEntry" name="buildQty" size="3" onchange="Calc()"/></td>
                    <td> <div id="carton">@item.cartonQty</div></td>
                    <td> <div id="weight">@item.weight</div></td>
                    <td><div id="cube">@item.cube</div></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                }
            }
```

So essentially I want to update the carton, weight and cube quantities when a user changes the text field for buildQty. I want each row to update. Right now only the first row updates even if I am updating the text on another row.

Comment: IDs have to be unique. That's your problem here.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. So maybe add on my seq counter variable to the end of each id and pass that to the function so I update the correct row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glaring issue: `id`'s are meant to be *unique*. Yours are not. So it only accesses the first one. Try this as a change:

markup:

```
<tr>
              <td>@seq</td>
                <td>@item.sku</td>
                <td>@item.description</td>
                <td><input type=text id="qtyEntry@(seq)" name="buildQty@(seq)" size="3" onchange="Calc(@(seq))"/></td>
                <td> <div id="carton@(seq)">@item.cartonQty</div></td>
                <td> <div id="weight@(seq)">@item.weight</div></td>
                <td> <div id="cube@(seq)">@item.cube</div></td>
                <td></td>
</tr>
```

js:

```
function Calc(seq) {
 var qty = 0;
 qty=parseInt(document.getElementById('qtyEntry'+seq).value);
 var weight = parseInt(document.getElementById('weight'+seq).innerHTML);
 var cube = parseInt(document.getElementById('cube'+seq).innerHTML);
 var carton = parseInt(document.getElementById('carton'+seq).innerHTML);

 var newWeight = 0;
 var newCube = 0;
 var newCarton = 0;

 newWeight = qty *weight ;
 newCube = qty * cube;
 newCarton = qty * carton;

 document.getElementById('weight'+seq).innerHTML = newWeight;
 document.getElementById('cube'+seq).innerHTML = newCube;
 document.getElementById('carton'+seq).innerHTML = newCarton;
}
```

But note! This could possibly change your model binding and you will need to revisit the way you are going to accept this from your post. I would assume it is not properly posting as it is right now because the `name` is also not unique (and that is part which has to do with model binding).

Comment: Thanks Travis J. That worked perfectly and was what I was thinking I needed to do. Luckily I am not posting at this point, just trying to do some calculations on the table data and then sending it to another database.